# Collect data from email message

Tags: php, mysql, email

I want to collect data from email to mysql database using php.

If some one is sent a mail to their mail account to my mail id. I want that mail information to store in my database. for further operation. It is possible in PHP because  I saw this feature in one hosting support application [Kayako Fusion](http://www.kayako.com/products/fusion/) which developed by PHP.

So plese give some information to do this task.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse with PHP the best way is to use a 3rd party API to revive the email and then send it to your PHP script with a HTTP Post.

I'd recommend using either [sendgrid.com](http://www.sendgrid.com) or [mailgun.com](http://www.mailgun.com)

Both of these services will parse the email and send you the information in a http POST that you can then insert into mysql. API docs for both: [MailGun Incoming Parse API](http://documentation.mailgun.net/user_manual.html#receiving-messages-via-http) / [SendGrid Incoming Parse API](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [imap functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php), for example:

```
<?php
$imap = imap_open("{server.example.com:143}INBOX" , 'login' , 'password');

if( $imap ) {

     //Check no.of.msgs
     $num = imap_num_msg($imap);

     //if there is a message in your inbox
     if( $num >0 ) {
          //read that mail recently arrived
          $the_message = imap_body($imap, $num);

          //Do the stuff with $the_message
     }

     //close the stream
     imap_close($imap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to setup a cronjob (scheduled task on Windows) that connects to the Exchange or POP server, retrieve's all new emails sinds the last run and insert them into the DB.

In case of a POP mail server(I think POP will be easier), there is a comment here with all functions you need right -> [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php). If that doesn't work, try Googling for "PHP POP wrapper" or something similar.

In case of a Microsoft Exchange server, you'd have to use a PHP Exchange wrapper, found one [here](http://code.google.com/p/php-ews/) for you.

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your email to a php script and then extract each part of email and store it in data base.

**[check this example](http://www.phpshare.org/articles/Piping-Incoming-Mail-with-PHP)**

when you get content of email you can do what ever you want